# What is the best way to setup existing magento project with apple M2 chip?

Tags: elasticsearch, setup, macbook

I have tried to install it using markshust/docker-magento but it gives errors in elasticsearch as elasticsearch is now deprecated in M2 chips and I am not sure how to configure magento2 with opensearch.

[image]

Comment: this is issue of elasticsearch check your elasticsearch status

Answer (score 1):

For me I use Symfony Local Web Server for a web server.
Link : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html

And for elasticsearch : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/brew.html

Opensearch is a fork of elasticsearch have same configuration for Magento 2.
Link : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/prepare/opensearch-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with Laravel Valet, It's a nice development environment tool for Magento in Mac.
You can follow this documentation link for installation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked well with https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento but then I changed the elasticsearch host name to OpenSearch and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below setting on given path it is set or not. if not configured so just do it.

`Admin -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Save config`

[image]

You can also set it from the database table on table `core_config_data`. see below image for the table. but before changes take backup of table.

[image]